# Validation doesn't work on EntityManager.merge()

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I have few validations on my entity, like `@NotNull`, and some generation, like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long referenceNumber;
```

However when calling `EntityManager.merge()` this values are not generated. Null fields with `@NotNull` annotation are passed without any complain. Even `id` is not generated.

Should I switch this generation on somehow? How, and where?

Comment: You complained two behaviors. One is `id-generation` and the other is `bean-validation on merge()`. @axtavt answered about the former and @kraftan answered about the latter. And I voted up for @kraftan's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to kraftan's answer:

- By default automatic bean validation in JPA 2.0 works if validation provider is "present in the environment", otherwise it silently doesn't work. You can add

  ```
  <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
  ```

  to `persistence.xml` in order to generate an error if validation provider is not found.
- JPA doesn't support generation of arbitrary (non-id) properties. Some JPA providers may have [extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e2859).

Answer (score 7):

`Merge()` does not invoke pre-insert/pre-update event listeners by default. `flush()` after the `merge()` should do it.

Comment: I can confirm this. Thanks. Is this feature specified?