# Validation doesn't work with persist

Tags: java, spring, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x, JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. The application run on Tomcat 6.X.

I use the bean validation in my entities. Hibernate Validator is the provider, version 4.2.0.Final.

```
@NotEmpty(message="{site.checklangs}")
    @OrderBy("position ASC")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<SiteLanguage> langs;
```

The `@NotEmpty` work for `persist` but not for `merge`

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Site updateSite(Site site) {
        return entityManager.merge(site);
    }
```

This doesn't throw any exceptions when my list is empty. Why ? How fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `entityManager.flush();` after `merge()`;

See [Validation doesn't work on EntityManager.merge()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326030/validation-doesnt-work-on-entitymanager-merge) as reference.